# How to fix compression from Bloom in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compression

The bloom effect in my frames comes out with these compression waves no matter the format I export them in. Even in the preview mode of the viewport I can see it.. The only way I've seen that reduces them is by reducing the intensity of my bloom.. But I like it strong, just wishing it had more of a gradient feel to it. Any ideas on how to smooth it out with strong intensity and high contrast?

[image: Bloom effect compression waves, looks bad when animated]

Comment: Some images of final result may help understand what you mean

Comment: Don't you see the concentric circles (or waves) around the bloom?

Comment: I managed to get less banding by exporting with Maximum Depth in Quicktime 444 HQ